# C# Linq Consolidate by ID and Sum Quantities

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a simple setup (below). Each "Assembly" contains a list of parts. There may be repeated "Part" objects within the assembly.

My goal is to consolidate the Part Objects (by id) and sum the quantities.

The end result should look like this (Where the quantities per each Part were summed):

```
[Assembly 1]
  [3] Part 1  
  [8] Part 2
  [4] Part 3

[Assembly 2]
  [3] Part 1
  [15] Part 3
```

Check out the code below under "CONSOLE OUTPUT" for what I'm currently getting.

I've tried the following LINQ (failed):

```
List<Assembly> listAssy2 = listAssy.SelectMany(a => a.listParts.GroupBy(b => b.qty)).ToList();
```

The Code:

```
public class Part {
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
}

public class Assembly {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Part> listParts { get; set; }
}


public static void Main()
{       
    List<Assembly> listAssy = new List<Assembly>();

    // ----------------- ASSEMBLY 1 -----------------
    //List of Parts
    List<Part> partList1 = new List<Part>();
    partList1.Add(new Part { id = 1, title = "Part 1", qty = 2 }); 
    partList1.Add(new Part { id = 1, title = "Part 1", qty = 1 }); 
    partList1.Add(new Part { id = 2, title = "Part 2", qty = 2 });
    partList1.Add(new Part { id = 3, title = "Part 3", qty = 4 });
    partList1.Add(new Part { id = 2, title = "Part 2", qty = 6 });

    Assembly assy1 = new Assembly {id = 1, title = "Assembly 1", listParts = partList1};
    listAssy.Add(assy1);

    // ----------------- ASSEMBLY 2 -----------------
    //List of Parts
    List<Part> partList2 = new List<Part>();
    partList2.Add(new Part { id = 1, title = "Part 1", qty = 2 }); 
    partList2.Add(new Part { id = 3, title = "Part 3", qty = 4 }); 
    partList2.Add(new Part { id = 3, title = "Part 3", qty = 11 });
    partList2.Add(new Part { id = 1, title = "Part 1", qty = 1 });

    Assembly assy2 = new Assembly {id = 2, title = "Assembly 2", listParts = partList2};
    listAssy.Add(assy2);



    foreach (var assy in listAssy) {
        Console.WriteLine("[" + assy.title + "]");
        foreach (var part in assy.listParts) {
            Console.WriteLine("  [" + part.qty + "] " + part.title);    
        }   
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    /* ***** CONSOLE OUTPUT ******
      [Assembly 1]
        [2] Part 1
        [1] Part 1
        [2] Part 2
        [4] Part 3
        [6] Part 2

      [Assembly 2]
        [2] Part 1
        [4] Part 3
        [11] Part 3
        [1] Part 1 

    */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var summaries = listAssy
    .Select(a => new {
        a.id,
        a.title,
        partQuantities = a.listParts.GroupBy(p => new { p.id, p.title })
            .Select(g => new { g.Key.id, g.Key.title, qty = g.Sum(p => p.qty)})
            .ToList()
    });

foreach (var assy in summaries)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[" + assy.title + "]");
    foreach (var part in assy.partQuantities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  [" + part.qty + "] " + part.title);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```